# How to rotate one image in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas

I am making an HTML5 canvas game, and I wish to rotate one of the images.

```
var link = new Image();
link.src='img/link.png';
link.onload=function(){
    ctx.drawImage(link,x,y,20,20); // draws a chain link or dagger
}
```

I wish to rotate this image. The standard way of rotating image was to set a rotation on the canvas context object. However, that rotates the entire game! I don't want to do that, and only wish to rotate this one sprite. How do I do that?

Comment: 18,000 views and 4 upvotes...that's kinda odd

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `.save()` and `.restore()` ([more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations#Basic_animation_steps)):

```
link.onload=function(){
    ctx.save(); // save current state
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI); // rotate
    ctx.drawImage(link,x,y,20,20); // draws a chain link or dagger
    ctx.restore(); // restore original states (no rotation etc)
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks! Do you have an idea about the maths for redoing the dimensions of the image when I am doing arbitrary angle rotation?

Comment: @Razor Storm: You'd need to translate the midpoint and translate it back, but you managed to do so already as you posted.

Comment: I believe it is better performing to do an inverse rotation after drawImage, instead of saving and restoring.

Comment: @Gustavo6046 thats what everybody else is saying everywhere else that ive looked so far

Comment: is there any way to rotate the `drawImage` element without rotating the `canvas` itself?

Comment: @oldboy I think it's easier to rotate the canvas and then unrotate right after you're done with your stuff? Maybe extract this functionality into a function to be extra sure issues don't arise from this. Even a decorator if you care so much, like f(g()) { return function new_g() { do_stuff_before(); g(); do_stuff_after(); } }

Answer (score 6):

You might want to put a `translate();` there because the image is going to rotate around the origin and that is in the top left corner by default so you use the `translate();` to change the origin.

```
link.onload=function(){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y); // change origin
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
    ctx.drawImage(link,-10,-10,10,10);
    ctx.restore()
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the positions are still messed up

Comment: ok so u have a position u want to draw a image which will be (x, y). so what u want to do is to translate the origin (0, 0) to the position (x, y) so that position is now (0, 0) u  and draw ur image right on top of the origin. so if ur image is 20px high and wide ctx.drawImage(link,-10,-10,10,10); and u will be able to rotate the image around its center.

Answer (score 5):

Your original "solution" was:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x,y);
ctx.rotate(-this.angle + Math.PI/2.0);
ctx.translate(-x, -y); 
ctx.drawImage(this.daggerImage,x,y,20,20);
ctx.restore();
```

However, it can be made more efficient (with no `save` or `restore`) by using this code:

```
ctx.translate(x,y);
ctx.rotate(-this.angle + Math.PI/2.0);
ctx.drawImage(this.daggerImage,x,y,20,20);
ctx.rotate(this.angle - Math.PI/2.0);
ctx.translate(-x, -y);
```

Comment: Oh, nice! I'll use this in _my_ game.

Comment: is there any way to rotate the `drawImage` element without rotating the `canvas` itself?

Answer (score 5):

Look at my solution. It's full example and the easiest to understand.

```js
    var drawRotate = (clockwise) => {
        const degrees = clockwise == true? 90: -90;
        let canvas = $('<canvas />')[0];
        let img = $(".img-view")[0];

        const iw = img.naturalWidth;
        const ih = img.naturalHeight;

        canvas.width = ih;
        canvas.height = iw;

        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        if(clockwise){
            ctx.translate(ih, 0);
        } else {
            ctx.translate(0, iw);
        }

        ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        let rotated = canvas.toDataURL();        
        img.src = rotated;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here i made a working example from one of my games. u can get the image from [Here](http://www.justawebsite.co.cc/images/ship.png).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var play = setInterval('Rotate()',16);
var i = 0;
var shipImg = new Image();
shipImg.src = 'ship.png';

function Rotate() {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(50, 50);
  ctx.rotate(i / 180 / Math.PI);
  ctx.drawImage(shipImg, -16, -16);
  ctx.restore();
  i += 10;
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there any way to rotate the `drawImage` element without rotating the `canvas` itself?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to do:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x,y);
ctx.rotate(-this.angle + Math.PI/2.0);
ctx.translate(-x, -y); 
ctx.drawImage(this.daggerImage,x,y,20,20);
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: you just need the x and y value in the first translate and you can remove the second translate and stop putting the x and y values in the `drawImage();` you are just doubling the values, instead `drawImage(this.daggerImage,-10,-10,10,10);`. There is more info on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations about this stuff