# Issues in canvas image rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I've created a basic HTML5 image slider where images move from top to bottom in a canvas.
I want all the images rotated at angle of 5 degrees. When I tried it out there seems to be some
distortion to the canvas and the image is not properly rotated.

I've tried the method for rotation mentioned in the below post

[How do I rotate a single object on an html 5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677671/how-do-i-rotate-a-single-object-on-an-html-5-canvas)

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/DS2Sb/

Code

```
this.createImage = function (image, width, height) {

    var fbWallImageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var fbWallImageCanvasContext = fbWallImageCanvas.getContext('2d');
    fbWallImageCanvas.width = width;
    fbWallImageCanvas.height = height;

    fbWallImageCanvasContext.save();
    fbWallImageCanvasContext.globalAlpha = 0.7;
    this.rotateImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, 5, fbWallImageCanvasContext);
    fbWallImageCanvasContext.drawImage(image, width, height);
    fbWallImageCanvasContext.restore();
    return fbWallImageCanvas;
};

this.rotateImage = function (image, x, y, width, height, angle, context) {

    var radian = angle * Math.PI / 180;
    context.translate(x + width / 2, y + height / 2);
    context.rotate(radian);
    context.drawImage(image, width / 2 * (-1), height / 2 * (-1), width, height);
    context.rotate(radian * (-1));
    context.translate((x + width / 2) * (-1), (y + height / 2) * (-1));

};
```

Comment: Your code will draw the image twice to an offscreen canvas: one rotated, one not rotated. Is that what you want the code to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distortion you see is due to the fact that a rotated image will only fit in a larger canvas. So what we see is a rectangle view on a rotated image.
The computations are not that easy to get things done properly, but instead of pre-computing the rotated image, you might rotate them just when you draw them, which lets you also change the angle whenever you want (and opacity also btw).

So i simplified createImage, so that it just stores the image in a canvas (drawing a canvas is faster than drawing an image) :

```
this.createImage = function(image , width, height) {
    var fbWallImageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    fbWallImageCanvas.width = width;
    fbWallImageCanvas.height = height;  
            var fbWallImageCanvasContext = fbWallImageCanvas.getContext('2d');
    fbWallImageCanvasContext.drawImage(image,0,0);
    return fbWallImageCanvas;
};
```

And i changed drawItem so it draws the image rotated :

```
this.drawItem = function(ct) {
        var angle = 5;
        var radian = angle * Math.PI/180;
        ct.save();
        ct.translate(this.x + this.width/2 , this.y + this.height/2);
        ct.rotate(radian);
        ct.globalAlpha = 0.7;
        ct.drawImage(fbc, - this.width/2, -this.height/2 , this.width, this.height);
        ct.restore();
        this.animate();
    };
```

You'll probably want to refactor this, but you see the idea.

fiddle is here :
  http://jsfiddle.net/DS2Sb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a small html5 tutorial I created a while ago:

https://bitbucket.org/Garlov/html5-sidescroller-game-source

And here is the rotate code:

```
// save old coordinate system
ctx.save(); 
// move to the middle of where we want to draw our image
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height-64);
// rotate around that point
ctx.rotate(0.02 * (playerPosition.x));
//draw playerImage
ctx.drawImage(playerImage, -playerImage.width/2, -playerImage.height/2);
//and restore coordniate system to default
ctx.restore();
```